# Jscript - stuck with hide/reveal divs

Tags: javascript, web, onclick, show-hide

I'm currently working on a website and in my mainContent div i have 5 divs. 1 div is visible by default and the other 4 are hidden (note: the default visible div corresponds to home page content). I also have 5 links in a sideMenu that correspond to each of the hidden/visible divs.

The goal that i am trying to achieve is the following using Jscript:

- when clicking one of the links from the sideMenu i would like the corresponding div to be made visible(if hidden) and the rest of the divs hidden.

Could anybody help with any pointers?

attempt at an illustration:

->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Default Home page:

link1 | link2 | link3

contentDiv:

div1 - visible

div2 - hidden

div3 - hidden

->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Link2 was pressed:

link1 | LINK2 | link3

contentDiv:

div1 - hidden

div2 - visible

div3 - hidden

Comment: Are you using plain old JavaScript or are you using a library like jQuery? And can you show your HTML?

Comment: @hradac: What is "old" JavaScript?

Comment: @Amberlamps "Old" being just a euphemism basically meaning that it's just JavaScript, no libraries or anything like that.

Comment: @hradac: I cannot see any euphemism in there, I´d rather call it dysphemism. But I am splitting hairs here :)

Comment: @Amberlamps I use the expression "plain old JavaScript" in the same way that the term POJO (Plain Old Java Object) is used. It is intended to indicate its use without extras or frills. If "old" were meant as a pejorative then you would be correct in calling it a dysphemism. However, since JavaScript first appeared about 17 years ago I could see how you might think I was being derogatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all content divs a common class name, e.g. 'contentPanel' and each one a unique ID, like `#home-panel`, `#page1-panel`, etc. You should style all these with `display:none` except the home div. Set up your links like this:

```
<a href="#home-panel" class="panel-link">Home</a>
<a href="#page1-panel" class="panel-link>Page1</a>
<!-- etc.. -->
```

For the script, one suggestion is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It might look like

```
$(".panel-link").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".contentPanel").hide();
    $(target).show();
});
```

If you'd like the script to run correctly in parallel with browser history changes, check out Ben Alman's jQuery hash change plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/. I  used this on my old website: http://paislee.net/.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery and do something like this

```
function changePage(page){
    $('#contentDiv').children('div').each(function(){
         if($(this).css('display') != 'none')
         {
              $(this).css('display', 'none'))
         }
});

      switch(page){
         case 1:
             //make home visible
         break;
         case 2:
             //make about visible
         break;
         case 3:
             //make contact visible
         break;

       }
}
```

These buttons are in the side bar, when clicked, they go to the function, hides the currently displaying page, and then uses a switch to decide what new page to display

```
<button onclick="changePage(1)">Home</button>
<button onclick="changePage(2)">About</button>
<button onclick="changePage(3)">Contact</button>
```

P.s. I haven't actually checked this code, but I think you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Say your html is something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a  class='link' data-linkno='1' href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a class='link' data-linkno='2' href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a class='link' data-linkno='3' href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class='content' id='div1">blah</div>
<div class='content' id='div2">blah</div>
<div class='content' id='div3">blah</div>
```

The following jQuery or something similar should work

```
 $(function() {
       $(".link").live("click", function(e) {
       $(".content").hide();
       $("#div"+$(this).data("linkno")).show();
        })
    })
```

Comment: i understand everything except the 4th line...do you mind explaining the 4th line?

Comment: I think you mean the last relevant bit of jQuery-- $(this).data("linkno")) should return the value of the data-linkno attribute for the item that was clicked. .show() will show the corresponding <div>. For example, clicking on link 2, with data-linkno=2, will trigger the jQuery show function for the element with the ID of div2